# How to make a number out of other numbers in mathematica?

Tags: mathematica

I’m not entirely sure if this is possible, but I would like to make numbers composed of other numbers. For example, given $a$, $b$, and $c$, I’d like to make a number such that the digits are $a.bc$.

So, if $a = 1$, $b = 2$, and $c = 3$, we would have the number $1.23$. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Sure, use powers of $10$: $1.23=1\cdot 10^0+2\cdot 10^{-1}+3\cdot 10^{-2}$

Comment: This is not clear.  You can write out any number you want.  That said, I don't understand your construction.  Are $a,b,c$ meant to be positive integers?   What would you do with $a=101, b=202,c=303$?  Would you write $101.202303$?  That would make sense, but I can't imagine what you have in mind if $a,b,c$ are irrational or negative.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @lulu: OP mentions that $a$, $b$ and $c$ are digits. But I agree with you that the way the digits are combined is not defined.

Comment: @Vasya  Where is it said that $a,b,c$ are digits?

Comment: @lulu $a$, $b$, and $c$ are positive integers

Comment: That should be added to the post.  If you are looking for code that does what you want you will need to first write a function that gives you the number of digits in an integer, so $n(b)=\lfloor \log_{10}(b) \rfloor+1$ or such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
 FromDigits[{a, b, c}] // Simplify
```

> 100 a + 10 b + c

For your example:

```
 FromDigits[{1, 2, 3}]/100.
```

> 1.23

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as you know what you want to do and you do the mathematics correctly, go ahead and create new numbers out of the old ones.

That is a good way to understand numbers better.

They have created the set of positive integers starting at 1 and adding one each time.

$$1, 1+1=2, 2+1=3,....$$

Comment: Mathematica also does the negative integers